# angular2 routes TypeError: Cannot read property 'forRoot'

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

angular2 rc.5

I am getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'forRoot' of undefined(…)`
when i investigated i found that `RouterModule` is `undefined`  during execution.

Following is my app.route.ts

```
import {Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

//const routes: Routes = [];
import {HelloComponent} from './hello.component';
import {IncComponent} from './inc.component';
import {AdditionComponent} from './addition.component';
import {RomanComponent} from './roman.component';

let routes: Routes = [

    {
        path: 'hello',
        component: HelloComponent
    },
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/hello',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    {
        path: 'increment',
        component: IncComponent
    },{
        path: 'adder',
        component: AdditionComponent
    },{
        path: 'roman',
        component: RomanComponent
    }
];


export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(routes); // error on this line
```

Following is my app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
import {routing} from './app.routes';
import {HelloComponent} from './hello.component';
import {IncComponent} from './inc.component';
import {AdditionComponent} from './addition.component';
import {RomanComponent} from './roman.component';

@NgModule({
    imports:[
        BrowserModule,
        routing
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        HelloComponent,
        IncComponent,
        AdditionComponent,
        RomanComponent
    ],
    bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

and main.ts

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
    //import { HTTP_PROVIDERS } from '@angular/http';
    import { AppModule } from './app.module';

    platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

Comment: Possible reason is your `systemjs.config.js` file doesn't have `router module` reference.

Comment: You have to produce it in plunker only. after RC5 things have become tough to figure out.

Comment: Do you find solution?

Comment: Facing a similiar problem, finally noticed that I was importing from the wrong library import { SortablejsModule } from 'angular-sortablejs'; not from from 'sortablejs';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

source [package.json](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/npm-packages.html)
i have copied the dependencies from the answered above.

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/forms": "0.3.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/router-deprecated": "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "core-js": "^2.4.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12",
    "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.15",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^2.0.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.0",
    "typescript": "^1.8.10",
    "typings": "^1.0.4"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
Maybe it's corny, but in my case, problem was solved after I cleared the browser cache.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue working in a .NET Core web application in Visual Studio 2015. I upgraded my packages from rc4 to rc5, did an `npm install` and saw this error after I refreshed my browser. I eventually realized that I forgot to copy the updated packages from node_modules to my lib folder inside wwwroot (I have a gulp task that does this). After running the task to update the libs everything was back to normal. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

I'm running under Visual Studio but I had to do all of the following steps:

1. delete my bin, obj, node_modules folders
2. npm install
3. run my gulp scripts that copy the .js files around
4. clear browser cache

Answer (score 0):

I was having the exact same problem and it was because I had an outdated version of Angular 2.

Here is the up-to-date (as we speak) version of the package.json file :

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/forms": "0.3.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/router-deprecated": "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "core-js": "^2.4.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12",
    "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.15",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^2.0.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.0",
    "typescript": "^1.8.10",
    "typings": "^1.0.4"
  }
}
```

Update you package.json file with the latests versions, run npm install again and it should work.

You can get the latests versions [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/npm-packages.html).

Answer (score 0):

For me it was problem with webpack - I had 2 js files: `vendor.js` and `app.js`. I'm using CommonsChunkPlugin to load required vendor libraries. I set the name option the same as one of the entry points. This was my previous config:

```
new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
    name: 'common'
})
```

I've changed only one thing: added `filename` option and it started to work:

```
new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
    name: 'common',
    filename: "vendor.js"
})
```

I don't know if this is the same case, but it solved my problem.